# Invisible text in terminal with yarn

Tags: windows, terminal, visual-studio-code, git-bash, yarnpkg

I have a bug with Yarn and terminal (on Windows 10). When I use `yarn add`, `yarn start` etc then the first several lines are invisible and empty space appears.

For example, I have test.js with console.log('Hi console'). 
When I use `yarn start` (screen 1).

[image]

When I use `npm start.js` - it's ok. And then If I use `yarn start` - it's ok too. (screen 2).

But using 'yarn' standalone - making this bug.

[image]

Also I tried `reset`. Did not help.

Answer (score 2):

So, it is March 2020 and I encountered this problem with Yarn **1.22.1**, running VS Code Insiders on Windows 10. The OP's screenshots above show the problem, with the version of Yarn printed, followed by rows of empty space before returning to the prompt after apparently ignoring the command.

According to [**vscode issue #72145**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72145), "This is a bug in Windows 10 1809, unfortunately we have no way to work around the issue so you will need to wait until you get the next version of Windows 10 (1903)" ("Tyriar", April 11, 2019).

The fix the terminal in VS Code for me was to [**upgrade to Yarn v.2**](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry), which was just released in January 2020.

Yarn 2 has a lot of differences to Yarn 1, however, so you would want to read the [**Yarn 2 Migration docs**](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/migration) before deciding if upgrading is the best course of action for your project. The chunk of empty space still appeared after upgrading, but was followed by the correct output in response to the Yarn commands.

Before upgrading to Yarn 2, if you don't want to do that yet, the workaround was to open the Windows 10 Command Prompt, cd into the project directory, and run the Yarn commands from that CLI. Using the Windows CLI correctly showed the correct output to Yarn commands where Git Bash did not.

Hope this might help someone.